# How to display the custom created tooltip always on the right side of the element or next to the element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I am developing a Nuxt 3-based application where creating a reusable custom tooltip menu bar which can display some information on hovering over the `vee-validate Field` that I want to reuse for various other components. For some reason the tooltip menu displays below the Field instead of displaying next to the Field on the right side.

How to fix the styles using the tailwind CSS to ensure that the tooltip menu always appears on the right side next to the Field? I have added the sample code in my [CodeSandbox for reference](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/admiring-bas-3kh2ws?embed=1&file=%2Fpages%2Findex.vue%3A12%2C38).

Following are my Nuxt 3 application codes:

`components/CustomToolTip.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div class="relative">
      <div
        class="focus:outline-none"
        @mouseover="startHover"
        @mouseleave="endHover"
        @click="hidePopover"
      >
        <slot />
      </div>
  
      <div
        v-show="showTooltip"
        class="fixed z-50 dark:bg-gray-700 bg-gray-300 dark:text-white text-black rounded-lg p-2 inline-block after:absolute after:border-4 dark:after:border-gray-700 after:border-gray-300 after:-left-0 after:top-1/3 after:-translate-x-1/2 after:rotate-45 transform -translate-y-[30%]"
        :style="{ left: tooltipPosition, top: tooltipTopPosition }"
        @mouseover="showTooltip = true"
        @mouseleave="hidePopover"
      >
        <div
          class="max-w-xs max-h-20 overflow-auto"
          @mouseenter="cancelHideTimer"
          @mouseleave="hidePopover"
        >
          {{ tooltipInfo }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
   
  <script setup>
  import { ref } from "vue";
  
  const props = defineProps({
    name: {
      type: String, // name associated with the field
      required: false,
    },
    fieldName: {
      type: String, //name associated with HoverIcon
      required: false,
      default: "",
    },
    fieldValue: {
      type: [String, Boolean, Number], //value associated with hoverIcon
      required: false,
      default: "",
    },
  });
  
  // Reactive state
  const showTooltip = ref(false); //To hide/show the tooltip info menu
  const tooltipInfo = ref(""); // To get the info from tooltipInfo
  const tooltipPosition = ref(""); //To fix the position
  const tooltipTopPosition = ref("");
  const hideTimer = ref(null);
  const hoverTimestamp = ref(null);
  
  // Show the tooltip info by fixing the position after 2 seconds of hover over the Field
  const startHover = (event) => {
    hoverTimestamp.value = Date.now();
    showPopover(event);
  };
  
  //Hide the tooltip info if mouse is left the field and ensure not to show during the click
  const endHover = (event) => {
    hoverTimestamp.value = null;
    startHideTimer();
  };
  
  // Cancel the timer to ensure during the click the tooltip menu is not shown
  const cancelHideTimer = (event) => {
    clearTimeout(hideTimer.value);
  };
  
  const startHideTimer = () => {
    hideTimer.value = setTimeout(() => {
      showTooltip.value = false;
    }, 300); // Adjust the delay as needed
  };
  
  // Show the tooltip info if the user has hovered over the element for more than 2 seconds
  const showPopover = (event) => {
    // Check if previous timer exists, if yes, clear it
    if (hideTimer.value !== null) {
      clearTimeout(hideTimer.value);
    }
  
    // Start the timer only if the user has hovered for more than 2 seconds
    hideTimer.value = setTimeout(() => {
      // Check if the user is still hovering over the element
      if (hoverTimestamp.value && Date.now() - hoverTimestamp.value >= 2000) {
        const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        tooltipPosition.value = `${rect.right + 10}px`;
        tooltipTopPosition.value = `${rect.top + 10}px`;
        showTooltip.value = true;
        showToolTipInfo();
      }
    }, 2000);
  };
  
  //Hide the tooltip info if mouse is left the field and ensure not to show during the click
  const hidePopover = () => {
    clearTimeout(hideTimer.value);
    showTooltip.value = false;
  };
  
  //Function to fetch the tooltipInfo info based on the fieldName and fieldValue
  const showToolTipInfo = async () => {
    tooltipInfo.value = "HELLO FROM THE TOOLTIP WHERE I WILL DISPLAY SOME RANDOME INFORMATION DURING THE HOVER"
  };
  </script>
```

Following is my usage to wrap the other components to CustomTooltip.vue:
`components/HoverMenuTest2.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center w-full">
    <CustomToolTip :name="name" :fieldName="name" :fieldValue="''">
      <div
        class="relative w-full h-full bg-gray-50 dark:text-white dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 border-gray-300 border rounded text-center block overflow-hidden"
      >
        <Field
          as="select"
          :name="name"
          v-model="item"
          class="w-full h-full bg-transparent p-2 outline-none dark:bg-gray-700"
        >
          <option
            v-for="option in options"
            :value="option.value"
            :key="option.value"
            :selected="option.selected"
          >
            {{ option.text }}
          </option>
        </Field>

        <Icon
          icon="iconamoon:arrow-down-2-bold"
          class="absolute right-2 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2"
        />
      </div>
    </CustomToolTip>
  </div>
</template>
  
<script setup>
import { Icon } from "@iconify/vue";
import { Field } from "vee-validate";

const props = defineProps({
  options: {
    type: Array,
    required: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
});

const item = ref(props.options[0].value);
</script>
  
<style>
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-image: none;
}
</style>
```

Following is my usage in `pages/Test.vue`:

```
<template>
  <HoverMenuTest2 v-model="type" :name="'eventType'" :options="options" />
</template>

<script setup>
const type = useState("type", () => ({}));
const options = [
  { value: "value1", text: "Option 1", selected: true },
  { value: "value2", text: "Option 2" },
  { value: "value3", text: "Option 3" },
];
</script>
```

Currently when I hover over the Select dropdown then I get the tooltip as this:
[image]

I want it to be displayed next to the field something like this:
[image]

I tried with few styles etc but that does not seem to work and it modified the tooltip menu itself by striking its size and all, I want to ensure that the tooltip info bar is of the same size as expected but only need to move to the right side instead of displaying below the Field.

Comment: IMHO, a tooltip on a select or any element you can click can be confusing. What about mobile version ? I would just use an icon with a question mark which can show the tooltip on hover, on put the tooltip text besides the select.

Comment: @VincentDecaux I am not planning to add the icon as there are many fields and it looks bit ugly to have info icon next to all fields. Hence, I want to add the hover info when user hovers over the Field. Currrently I am using the timeout option to display the information with some delay so it does not interfere with the user clicks. I have updated code, please let me know if there is any better way than this.